# GAE Backend instance invocation and Spring integration

Tags: java, google-app-engine, spring-mvc, google-api

Google app engine documentation says :

> Backends share the set of servlets defined in web.xml with your main application version

We are using Spring Framework in our google engine app so we define only spring dispatcherServlet in web.xml my expectation is that Spring servlet with separate url can be triggered as "backend instance". However i dont know how to define url of spring servlet on given "subdomain".

i am trying to invoke backend "myBackendId" with queue task "doStuffQueue" :

```
Queue queue = QueueFactory.getQueue("doStuffQueue");
TaskOptions taskOptions = TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("/doTask/")
             .param("someParam", someParam)
             .header("Host", BackendServiceFactory.getBackendService().getBackendAddress("myBackendId"))
             .method(Method.POST);
   queue.add(taskOptions);
```

but TaskOption above runs this as standart frontend instance because subdomain is ignored so this url is called :

```
 myAppId.appspot.com/doTask
```

As workaround i tried to define TaskOption like this :

```
 TaskOptions.Builder.withUrl("myBackendId.myAppId.appspot.com/doTask")
```

but that`s not allowed in schema as url have to start with **/**

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, I suppose you may be having issues in the annotation definition.

Make it sure that you're using RequestMethod.POST. Also, I believe you may have to start the task urls with "/task/doTask" for example:

@RequestMapping(value = "/task/doTask", method = { RequestMethod.POST })